# Is there any French equivalent for the English "thou"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, pronoms, histoire, pronoms-personnels

I mean, in the same epoch that *thou* was most used in English. Like a contemporary equivalent, that is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the equivalent is *tu*. A few centuries ago, [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vouvoiement#English) had the same distinction as French: *thou* when addressing people at a certain level of familiarity, *you* in a formal or upper-class setting. In English, *you* became completely generalized and displaced *thou* (except when talking to God). In [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vouvoiement#French), the normal singular form remains in use. In some dialects (essentially, in France and in Switzerland), the syntactic plural *vous* may be used with a singular meaning, when speaking to a single person in formal situations. The limit between *tutoiement* (when to use *tu*) and *vouvoiement* (when to use *vous*) can be very difficult to grasp, it is a major difficulty for non-natives and is even occasionally awkward for natives.

Comment: In Belgium, too.

Comment: What's so hard to catch about the `vouvoiement`? Formal, respectful and meeting an new person, use vous. Otherwise, tu.

Comment: @Sebas There are plenty of social differences and ambiguous situations. Do you say *tu* or *vous* to your neighbor? (Depends: *vous* in most of France, but *tu* in many *banlieues*.) To a colleague? (I think *tu* is more common but it depends heavily on the industry.) To a complete stranger? (Usually *vous* but often *tu* among younger people and online.) Does it depend on the circumstances? (Yes, e.g. it's always *vous* in the army if the two persons are of different ranks.) Every native has had awkward occasions where one person picked *tu* and the other picked *vous*.

Comment: I think your questions can be summarised as I mention before: Repect, new acquaintance, formal, use `vous`. Otherwise, `tu`. Regarding to the *banlieues*, this is not a place where any correct french rule applies **anyway**.

Comment: @Sebas This isn't the place for this discussion, so this will be my last comment. Your summary is completely bogus. I respect plenty of people that I address as *tu*; it's not at all a matter of respect. Formality, yes, but the rules are intricate. There are plenty of contexts where one would say *tu* immediately (e.g. it's pretty common that the CEO of a company says *vous* to a *stagiaire* but *tu* to the newly-hired janitor.)

Answer (score 6):

### When *thou* was used as a colloquial singular second person

It was then used almost exactly as *tu* was at the same time in France, so you just have to map *thou* to *tu* and *you* to *vous*.

### When *thou* is used as an overly formal archaism

I tend to follow the convention used by the translators of David Eddings' *Belgariad*: to add French-like *tutoiement* and *vouvoiement* with respect to the familiarity between the characters, and to use pronouns with a capital first letter for *thou*, *thee*, *thine*…:

> *Mets toute Ta force d'âme à supporter Ton mal, ô aimable jouvenceau, l'exhorta jovialement Mandorallen […]*
>   *La reine des sortilèges*, translation by Dominique Haas

It was perhaps inspired from the classical pronouns referring to God in some French bibles or other religion-related work *Il*, *Tu*, *Son*… which translate to *thou* and such in King James' Bible.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to convey the same archaic meaning as "thou" with a personal pronoun in French, there is no equivalent.

Of course, the direct translation of "thou" is "tu" and although it does completely translate the meaning of "thou", it does not have any of the archaic connotations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 'Twould be interesting to see how the Shakespearean play between _thou_ and _you_, often in the same line, is rendered in French without losing too much of the original quibble interplay.

Comment: I'm not entirely familier with Shakespeare but I assume, "thou" would be translated as "tu" and "you" would be translated as "vous"... "You" in some cases may be translated as "On", but this would be less likely as the equivalent of "on" ("one") was widely used in Shakespearian English (I think)