# Le français à l'ancienne

Tags: histoire, conjugaison

Comme il y a la conjugaison archaïque en anglais (par exemple: *thou knowest*, *she knoweth*), est-ce qu'il existe une chose similaire en français? Par contre, cela exclut le vieux français.

Merci pour les réponses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sans parler du vieux français, il n'y a pas d'équivalent aux anciennes terminaisons de l'anglais au présent de l'indicatif, mais certains temps peu utilisés peuvent faire plus ou moins archaïque en français récent

- l'imparfait et le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif

  > Il était nécessaire qu'il parlât
  >   Je craignais que vous l'eussiez perdu
- Le passé antérieur

  > Ils eurent couru

Pour le pronom de la deuxième personne du singulier *thou*, voir [Is there any French equivalent for the English “thou”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6894/82).

Mais l'idéal serait sans doute d'aller pêcher dans le vieux français, de façon plus ou moins intense

> Tel disoit estre Socrates : parce que le voyans au dehors, & l’estimans par l’exteriore apparence, n’en eussiez donné un coupeau d’oignon ([Rabelais](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Gargantua/%C3%89dition_Juste,_1535))

Answer (score 3):

La difference entre "vieux français" et "français archaïque" est vague.

Dans les formes "pas trop vieilles", on peut citer [l'imparfait en -O-](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l%27indicatif#Formes_en_-o-) utilisé jusqu'au 18ème siecle.

- J'étois
- Tu étois
- Il, elle, on étoit
- Nous étoyons
- Vous étoyez
- Ils, elles étoyent